# Find what tables/columns a global temporary table pulls data from in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, temp-tables

I'm trying to find out where a temporary table in Oracle is pulling data from. This database is connected to a CMS.  It is my understanding that when a report is ran in the CMS Oracle creates a temporary table to generate the report.  In Oracle SQL developer I can find the table (empty) and view the column names. However, when I look at the sql that generates the data it just has column specification like "column_name number (9,0)". When I look at dependencies the name and referenced_name are the same, and the type is a synonym. I'm fairly new to the Oracle SQL Developer environment.

My goal is to use data from the report that is generated from the table, but I don't know where the data is coming from, nor do I know what the columns are called since a third party created these tables and I currently don't have access to the table definitions.

Any help would be much appreciated.  If I need to clarify something just let me know.  Thanks

Comment: A GTT isn't like a view, say; it can be populated by any code on an ad hoc basis, so there is no equivalent to the static text you can retrieve for a view's query from the data dictionary. You might get lucky and find the populating statement in `v$sql` I suppose, As a side issue, are you allowed to effectively reverse-engineer the third-party's code?

Comment: Hey Alex Poole, I'v looked at the SQL that produces the report, but the information I need is being drawn from the temp table (which I'm not sure were the temp table is getting its information from).

Comment: Yes, but unless whatever populates that temp table happens to still be in `v$sql`, Oracle doesn't keep a record of it from the perspective of that GTT. Possibly the report calls a procedure or function that populates it. You could look in `all_dependencies` to see if you can find references to it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try

```
select table_name from all_tables where temporary = 'Y';
```

This gives you the list of GTTs

There are two types, transaction specific and session specific.

If your GTT is transaction specific. ie,created with ON commit DELETE rows option then the data will be deleted once the transaction is committed.

If it is session specific. ie, created with ON commit PRESERVE rows option then data will be preserved until the session is closed. You can query it until then.

If you have DBA access find out the details with

```
set long 20000
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'GTT' ) from dual;
```

replace GTT with the original global temporary table name

But if you are trying to understand who puts data in GTT, you might try

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_dependencies
 WHERE referenced_name  = 'GTT'
   AND referenced_type  = 'TABLE'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_source
 WHERE UPPER(text) LIKE '%YOUR_GTT_NAME%';
```

Also you can query the GTT directly to find out the data in it and trace it back to source.